# Where to find a python module, py4cs?

Tags: python

I need the python moduel py4cs, but I cannot find it anywhere, it is not on pypi or anywhere else. Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: It is related to numpy, scientific.

Answer (score 1):

It is a set of tools useful for scientific programming in Python.  Initially, it was distributed as py4cs only with purchase of the book by Hans Petter Langtangen.  It is now called scitools and is widely available.

Answer (score 0):

It comes with the book "Python Scripting for Computational Science".

Comment: Yes there anyway I can download it?